# Downloading Files leads to "Uncaught TypeError" using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script to mass download pdf files so my friend doesn't have to do it manually. The goal is to download all pdfs on the page then proceed to the next page. I'll later add in a repeat but at this point I've gotten hung up on a problem. When I run the script I get an error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined
    at downloadfile (:12:19)
    at :21:11"

Because of the error it doesn't get to my else statement to go to the next page. Any ideas on what the issue is? The site unfortunately doesn't support jQuery. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('tableButtonImage');

function downloadfile(e, i) {
  var text = e.href;
  var pdflink =
    "https://iowalandrecords.org/imagerepositoryweb/imagestream/viewimage?" +
    text.substring(text.indexOf('?') + 1, text.length) +
    "&text=pdf";
  console.log(pdflink);

  downloadURI(pdflink, "jaredspdfs" + (i + 1) + ".pdf");
  if (i < links.length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      downloadfile(links[i + 1], i + 1);
    }, 500);
  } else {
    [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a")).forEach(function(ele) {
      if (ele.innerHTML === "Next") {
        ele.click()
      }
    })
  }
}
downloadfile(links[0], 0);
```

Comment: This error means that `links` is empty, so `links[0]` is undefined.

Comment: Well, the error is that somewhere, you're trying to get the `href` property on something that is undefined. I suspect it's the first line of `downloadfile`, `var text = e.href`. I would try debugging the code line by line using the browser's debugging utility.

Answer (score 0):

The line number & error message indicates this line:

```
var text = e.href;
```

If on the line before that you add `console.log(e)` you'll see it is undefined or null - indicating the `links` array is empty.